# Invisible Overfull \hbox in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, warnings

For a few toc-entries with long titles getting wrapped I am getting `Overfull \hbox`es, which are not visible, if I don't use the `draft`-option of `memoir`. I wonder where they come from, and how to turn them off, as I don't want to just ignore them:

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\subsection{Places: River Banks, Charnel Grounds and Other Shared Locations}
\end{document}
```

producing the following output (black box for `Overfull \hbox`):

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: You get an even worse overfull if you switch to `book`. The main error here might be that the items in the toc are not raggedright, try adding `\setrmarg{3.55em plus 1fil}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lines before the last line of an entry in the table of contents are indented at the right by `\@tocrmarg`, default in class `memoir` and `article` is `2.55em`. The last line ends with a right aligned page number in a box, whose width is `\pnumwidth`, default in class `memoir` and `article` is `1.55em`. 
Thus the text part of the line is `1em` shorter than the text in the last line, as illustrated by the following example using rules:

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\HRuleFilll}{%
  \null
  \leaders\hrule\hskip 0pt plus 1filll\relax
  \kern0pt\relax
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\subsection{Places: River Banks, Charnel Grounds and Other Shared Locations}
\subsection{\HRuleFilll\protect\newline\HRuleFilll\protect\newline\HRuleFilll}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

I assume the rationale behind this, is to make the line with the page number easier detectable from the right.

Thus, Fran's [list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265698/16967) can be extended by another option:

Option 7: Making `\@tocrmarg` a little smaller. (It could be set to `\@pnumwidth`, but I have some doubts, that this looks better.)

Answer (score 8):

Option 1: Abbreviated version for the ToC:

```
\subsection[Short title]{Very Long Title}
```

Option 2: Force a  linebreak in the ToC

```
\subsection[Very long\newline title]{Very Long Title}
```

Option 3: Allow hyphenation in "Shared"

```
\hyphenation{Sha-red}
```

Option 4: As above, but using a soft hyphen

```
\subsection{Places: River Banks, Charnel Grounds and Other Sha\-red Locations}
```

Option 5: Rewrite the header

```
\subsection{River banks, charnel grounds and other locations} % (for example)
```

Option 6:

```
% Reminder: At the end of the day, just ignore a overfull \hbox 
% unnoticeable in the final version it is not such a bad idea.
```

Option 7: Settled  by [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265701/11604)

Option 8: Be tolerant (note that I'm not `;)`)*

```
\tolerance9999     % or \sloppy
\tableofcontents*
\tolerance200     % or \fuzzy
```

Option 9: For onepage ToC, a minipage:

```
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}   
\tableofcontents*
\end{minipage}
```

or even a `\parbox`:

```
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\tableofcontents*}
```

Comment: * [Inappropiate use of  emoticons?](https://xkcd.com/541/)

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to Option 8 by Fran, but possibly more "elegant", one can enclose the `\tableofcontents` command as such:

```
\begin{sloppypar}
\tableofcontents
\end{sloppypar}
```

This will produce a TOC possibly with more blank spaces than normal, but everything should be nicely aligned and without \hbox Overfull warnings.

The same works also for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, for which it may be more difficult to manually apply most of the other options.